# How to paint over silicon non-paintable caulk?

Tags: painting, caulking

I accidentally used some non-paintable silicon caulk on some trim.  Does anyone have experience recovering from this?  Mechanically removing it sounds slow and tedious.  I'm hoping something like BIN will adhere but would like for someone to share what has worked for them.

Similar to this [unanswered question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/110769/removing-silicone-caulk-from-wall-for-painting).

Comment: Can you put another layer of sealant / caulk over the top then paint on that?

Comment: perhaps, but I'd would probably cut and sand the old stuff before I bothered with that.   About the same effort and I know for certain I'd get a good finish.

Comment: Didn't you say that would be "slow and tedious"?

Comment: yup, I also used the caulk to fill in some nail holes, so its all over.  If I remove it mechanically, I know the surface will be good.  If I caulk over it again, not so sure how it will turn out.  If you could tell me that covering with paintable caulk works well in your experience, then I would consider it more seriously.

Comment: Paint will not stick to silicone, it will bead up. Removing it is the best option.

Comment: @AlaskaMan Actually, there are 'Paintable' silicon caulks available.  The paint on mine did bead up, which is when I realized my mistake and decided to ask for help here.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me...  I used a sander on the flat surfaces to remove any caulk there, but cutting the bead out of an inside corner was more difficult than I hoped.  So I caulked over that with some paintable caulk as @SolarMike suggested.  The inside bead ended up larger than I would like, but replacing all the trim would have been easier than cutting all that tenacious stuff out.  Paint now looks good.

Answer (score 0):

I’d advise against trying to paint over it, even with the best primers, I would use a caulk removal tool and carefully get under it.  You might get lucky and it will peel off in a long strip.  The caulk removal tool helps a lot in getting it off.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, now that I am getting accustomed to the format, I see others posted similar answers as mine as a comment.  Do you think I would have been better off making that "answer" a comment?

Comment: No, you did fine. People often have tentative answers as comments, but the goal is to get the best information into the formal question and answer. The only thing I'd suggest is to focus a bit more on what the question was, e.g. say why you recommend against painting.